# VS2015 replaces automatically unicode escapes in json with actual character

Tags: json, unicode, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I didn't find anything related to my problem in the whole web (so even not on stackoverflow) and I'm thinking that maybe I'm not searhcing with the right keywords...

Anyway here is my question:

Lately Visual Studio started to replace unicode escape sequences automatically with the real character e.g.: '\u00e4' will be replaced with 'ä'. It happens every time when I'm changing something on the json-file. If I'm doing the changes somewhere else I don't see that the replacement happened and Visual Studio doesn't mark this as a change (luckily SVN shows me this as change). Often I notice this problem not until I see it in the application.

Even when I try to correct this mistake with replacing 'ä' by copy & paste with '\u00e4' it will be directly converted to 'ä'. If I type '\u00e4' in manually everything is fine till next time.

What can cause this behaviour and how can I fix this? I'm also using Resharper and maybe this causes somehow the behaviour?

Comment: No fix needed. `'ä'` and `'\u00e4'` mean exactly the same in a JSON file, and any JSON parser will return `'ä'` as the string value in both cases.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working like that. In this JSON-files are UI-relevant strings defined and at least Chrome and Firefox will display some cryptic symbols in the UI instead of the wished characters. It is only working when these files contain the escaped codes. I'm using btw. dojo, esri jsapi and an additional framework (map.apps from con terra) as technical base for the UI/Frontend.